# Split a column value to mutliple columns pandas /python

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python/Pandas and have a data frame with two columns one a series and another a string.
I am looking to split the contents of a Column(Series) to multiple columns .Appreciate your inputs on this regard . 
This is my current dataframe content

```
    Songdetails                                         Density
0   ["'t Hof Van Commerce", "Chance", "SORETGR12AB...   4.445323
1   ["-123min.", "Try", "SOERGVA12A6D4FEC55"]           3.854437
2   ["10_000 Maniacs", "Please Forgive Us (LP Vers...   3.579846
3   ["1200 Micrograms", "ECSTACY", "SOKYOEA12AB018...   5.503980
4   ["13 Cats", "Please Give Me Something", "SOYLO...   2.964401
5   ["16 Bit Lolitas", "Tim Likes Breaks (intermez...   5.564306
6   ["23 Skidoo", "100 Dark", "SOTACCS12AB0185B85"]     5.572990
7   ["2econd Class Citizen", "For This We'll Find ...   3.756746
8   ["2tall", "Demonstration", "SOYYQZR12A8C144F9D"]    5.472524
```

Desired output is SONG , ARTIST , SONG ID ,DENSITY  i.e. split song details into columns.

for e.g. for the sample data

```
           SONG DETAILS                                        DENSITY
8   ["2tall", "Demonstration", "SOYYQZR12A8C144F9D"]    5.472524

SONG   ARTIST              SONG ID               DENSITY

2tall  Demonstration    SOYYQZR12A8C144F9D         5.472524
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you try this: `pd.DataFrame(data = list(df['Songdetails'].values), columns = ['SONG', 'ARTIST', 'SONG ID'])`

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
In [275]:

pd.DataFrame(data = list(df['Song details'].values), columns = ['Song', 'Artist', 'Song Id'])
Out[275]:
    Song         Artist             Song Id
0  2tall  Demonstration  SOYYQZR12A8C144F9D
1  2tall  Demonstration  SOYYQZR12A8C144F9D
```

For you please try: `pd.DataFrame(data = list(df['Songdetails'].values), columns = ['SONG', 'ARTIST', 'SONG ID'])`

Comment: Thanks , as requested in my question ,I am looking to add these columns to existing column density.So final data frame with 4 columns Song Artist SongID Density .That is where I am looking at a simple way

Comment: Thank you , i had a do an insert of column to the new data frame and was able to achieve what i needed thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thank you , i had a do an insert of column to the new data frame and was able to achieve what i needed thanks df2 = pd.DataFrame(series.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.split(','))))
df2.insert(3,'Density',finaldf['Density'])